# Is it ok to add properties to WordPress userSetting object directly?

Tags: javascript, wordpress

WordPress has a `utils.js` file which has provided four utility functions to manipulate settings and store them in a cookie. it also creates a global variable called `userSettings` with the following properties:

- `url`
- `uid`
- `time`
- `secure`

Now, my plugin also wants to create one/more properties and instead of creating a new object I thought I'd use the one WP has already created.

Is it a good idea to store my plugin settings in this object.
one of the properties is the full url of the website.